# Is it possible that function will get a parameter that can be int OR char?

Tags: functions

I'm trying to create a function that enters a key/value into a JSON file.

But, since value can be an `int` or `char`, I don't want to create 2 functions for each type.

Is there a way ?

```
void setValue(char *key, char* value){
        StaticJsonDocument<512> tempJDOC;
        tempJDOC[key]=value;
}
```

**EDIT1**

```
#ifndef myJSON_h
#define myJSON_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "FS.h"


class myJSON
{
private:
bool _useSerial=false;
char _filename[30];

public:
char *ver="myJSON_v1.1";
myJSON(char *filename, bool useserial=false);

bool file_exists();
bool file_remove();
bool format ();
bool FS_ok();

void saveJSON2file(JsonDocument& _doc);
void readJSON_file(JsonDocument& _doc);

void printJSON(JsonDocument& _doc);
void PrettyprintJSON(JsonDocument& _doc);

const char *getValue (char *key);

template <class T>
void setValue(const char *key, T value);
//void setValue(const char *key, char *value);

};
#endif
```

**EDIT2**

```
#ifndef myJSON_h
#define myJSON_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "FS.h"

#define LOG_LENGTH 4
#define DOC_SIZE 512

template <class T> // . <---- line added
class myJSON
{
private:
bool _useSerial=false;
char _filename[30];

public:
char *ver="myJSON_v1.1";
myJSON(char *filename, bool useserial=false);

bool file_exists();
bool file_remove();
bool format ();
bool FS_ok();

void saveJSON2file(JsonDocument& _doc);
void readJSON_file(JsonDocument& _doc);

void printJSON(JsonDocument& _doc);
void PrettyprintJSON(JsonDocument& _doc);

const char *getValue (const char *key);
void removeValue(const char *key);
// void setValue(const char *key, char *value); <--- comment out
void updateArray(char* array_key, int val);
void printFile();
void setValue(const char *key, T value); <---- Added

};
#endif
```

and in .cpp file :

```
void myJSON::setValue(const char *key, T value){
        StaticJsonDocument<512> tempJDOC;
        myJSON::readJSON_file(tempJDOC);
        tempJDOC[key]=value;
        myJSON::saveJSON2file(tempJDOC);
        myJSON::PrettyprintJSON(tempJDOC);
}
```

Comment: how will the code that calls the function decide if it's setting a number or a string?

Comment: Um... The title and the text of your question refers to `char` parameter. The code seems to suggest that you are actually talking about `char *` parameter. So, what is it? `char` or `char *`? These are two very different things. You have to edit your question and clarify that.

Comment: @AnT - you are right, but it is commented out at this point since as juraj and edgar suggested to use `template` - so I don't need to use `int` nor `char`

Comment: If you needed to pass either `int` or `char` you wouldn't need to do anything at all. You don't need any "templates". Just one `int` version of the function by itself would cover all cases, including `char`, since in C and C++ `char` is just a small integer type. So, again, why are you asking this question? What is the problem with `char` that triggered it? Again, the code you provided implies that you need `char *` (or, better, `const char *`). Not `char`, but `const char *`. You need to reflect it in your question, since currently neither the question not the accepted answer make sense.

Comment: And when you use template, you **are** using `int` or `const char *`, albeit you are doing it *implicitly*. The compiler does it for you. But again, it is a matter of `int` and `const char *`, not a matter of `int` and `char` as you stated in your question. `char` is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: my intention using this function is to be able to set and `int` or `char` values into a JSON that saves at the end to file. What @Juraj and Edgar suggested, to use templates, solved that.

Comment: "Solved" what problem? What is the original problem? In your question you are talking about writing two functions - for `int` and `char` - and call this a *problem* you want to solve. But why didn't you just simply use one function - `int` version - for both types? No templates necessary. Why did you decide that there is a "problem" here in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ you can create a template function. (The ArduinoJson `[]` operator is a template too.)

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

StaticJsonDocument<512> tempJDOC;

template <typename T>
void setValue(const char *key, T value){
  tempJDOC[key] = value;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  setValue("a", 5);
  setValue("b", "xyz");

  serializeJson(tempJDOC, Serial);
}

void loop() {
}
```

the compiler will create function based on this template for every different type you use as second parameter in your sketch

Comment: When trying to take such function and put it inside a library ( using `template` as noted here ), i get an error. how can it be done?

Comment: by "put it inside a library", you mean using it as class's method?

Comment: a method that uses template inside a class

Comment: add the code of the class to the Question. is it a class with separate .h and .cpp files? do you have the template<> part of function declaration in .h too?

Comment: pasted .h file inside my Q

Comment: why did you use <class T>? it should be `template <typename T>`

Comment: I try to follow example 2 in : https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/templates

Comment: see EDIT2 in my Q

Comment: you want a class with a template function, not a template class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972152/how-to-create-a-template-function-within-a-class-c

Comment: Yes I know... this is the closest I could find

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is “no, it's not possible”. You will have to use two
different functions. These two functions can share the same name, using
[function overloading](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/function-overloading). You can even have the compiler
write these functions for you, based on a template you provide, as shown
in Juraj's answer. These language features help provide the illusion of
there being a single function. But it's just an illusion, albeit a
useful one that helps with program readability. At the fundamental
level, you still have two different functions.

Comment: Edgar - thank you for explaining and usefull link. But I do not understand how Juraj's answer ( using template ) creates/ duplicates the function for other types

Comment: @Guy.D: Do a search for “C++ templates”. In short, every time you call `setValue()` with a new value type, the compiler creates a new version of the `setValue()` function suitable for that specific type.

Comment: I have in my answer: "the compiler will create function based on this template for every different type you use as second parameter in your sketch"

Comment: @EdgarBonet I use you link to try to implement this function inside a lib I make ( called `myJSON`, as you can see in edit 1 and edit 2 ). I'll appreciate your help once more